# Converter valor timestamp para data

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp

Tenho uma valor *timestamp* de uma data, `1389135600`, como posso converter esse valor para uma data deste gênero `27/12/2014`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que este número é um *timestamp* válido precisaria apenas criar uma data baseada nele. Como devemos considerar apenas os segundos, é multiplicado por 1000.

Com a data em mãos você pode usá-la no formato que desejar. O tipo data tem como fazer isto com métodos próprios para alguns formatos comuns, como por exemplo o `toLocaleDateString`.

A função `meuLog` foi usada só para facilitar a impressão.

```js
var date = new Date(1389135600*1000); // converte para data
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR")); //formata de acordo com o requisito
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/DateLocale.js).