# Como tratar retorno de campo tipo Timestamp via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Como converter essa sequência de números: 1555506548000 em uma data válida ?

Preciso fazer a seguinte comparação:

```
if (_valor[0] == item.DT_CRIADO_EM) {
    //Faz alguma coisa
};
```

Porém a data não está no formato desejado conforme descrito acima. Segue o trecho relevante do código:

**Resposta do AJAX**

```
success: function (response) {

    $.each(response.emailList, function (index, item) {

        console.log("item.DT_CRIADO_EM: " + item.DT_CRIADO_EM);  // <<---  item.DT_CRIADO_EM: /Date(1555506548000)/

        $("input[name='txtData[]']").each(function () { 
            var _valor = new Array();
            _valor.push($(this).data("dt_criado_em"));

            console.log("_valor[]: " + _valor[0]);               // <<---  _valor[]: 15/04/2019 00:00:00

            if (_valor[0] == item.DT_CRIADO_EM) {                // <<--- Preciso comparar as duas datas aqui
                //Faz alguma coisa
            };                              
        }); 

    });
},
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Converter valor timestamp para data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45234/converter-valor-timestamp-para-data)

Comment: Baixar esse plugin DateLocale.js ?

Comment: pf leia a resposta

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância mas preciso de mais ajuda, já li a resposta e implementei o código e dá erro trava o visual studio: var date = new Date(1555506548000 * 1000);

Comment: O valor de `item.DT_CRIADO_EM` é exatamente este (uma string com barras e tudo): `/Date(1555506548000)/`?

Comment: Exatamente @Sam ! Atualizei o post e adicionei um print do console.

Comment: não precisa baixar o plugin,só usar o código que está na resposta:
`var data = new Date(1555506548000).toLocaleDateString("pt-BR")`, e se quiser validar, só valor um `alert(data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tudo são strings (o valor em `item.DT_CRIADO_EM` e o valor da primeira posição da array `_valor[]`), você pode pegar o timestamp em `item.DT_CRIADO_EM` e converter em data. Pegar também a data em `_valor[0]`, tudo com `.match()` usando expressões regulares.

Em seguida é só converter os dois com `.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR")`, resultando ambos em datas no formato `dd/mm/aaaa`, e fazer a comparação no `if` (considerando que você deseja comparar apenas se uma data é igual a outra):

```js
var item = {
   DT_CRIADO_EM: "/Date(1555506548000)/"
}

var _valor = ['15/04/2019 00:00:00'];

// trata da data em _valor[0]
var valordata = _valor[0].match(/\d+\/\d+\/\d+/)[0].split("/");
var valordia = new Date(valordata[2], valordata[1]-1, valordata[0]).toLocaleDateString("pt-BR");

// trata da data em item.DT_CRIADO_EM
var criadoemdia = new Date(Number(item.DT_CRIADO_EM.match(/\d+/)[0])).toLocaleDateString("pt-BR");

console.log(valordia, criadoemdia);

if (valordia === criadoemdia){
   console.log("datas iguais");
}else{
   console.log("datas diferentes");
}
```

Comment: Perfeito @Sam ! Funcionou como esperava ! Obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

```
var timestamp = 1555506548000; // ou Date.now();
var date = new Date(timestamp);
var localDateString = date.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR"); // 17/04/2019
```

Pode testar [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bpz4b8).